# Simple barplot of variables in DF using a loop

Tags: r, loops, boxplot

Not having much experience at all writing loops, I'm looking to automate (with a loop) something I do frequently with all new datasets: create boxplots and histograms of each variable, as well as calculate descriptive statistics, for the latter, I tend to use both describe (Hmisc) and/or stats (fileds).

Ideally, I'd like to have the loop produce one boxplot for each appropriate variable.  My loop below produces only one boxplot and returns the error:

Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level

What am I getting wrong?  Also, if anyone could point me to a reference/website that may straighten out my insufficient loop-writing ways, I'd love the help.

Thanks!
Chris

```
y <- LETTERS[as.integer(rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=1))]
z <- LETTERS[as.integer(rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=1))]
x <- round(rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=2.5),2)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))


A<- do.call("cbind", lapply(data, class))
B<- as.vector( A[1,])
C <- grep("character|factor", B)

for (i in 1:length(C)) {
  x <- C[i]
  counti <- table(data[,x])
  y <- barplot(counti, main=paste("Barplot for var", x))
  return(y)}
```

Comment: Why you add `return(y)` to you for loop? Remove it and your loop will work like expected.

Comment: I would point you to the  [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)  to help get a handle on avoiding loops.  And toward `ggplot2` and specifically `facet_wrap` for this kind of plotting.

Comment: Excellent point Justin.  I don't think the `1:length(C)` is necessary, just pass the C directly as I did.  Then you can get rid of `x <- C[i]` and anywhere else you have `x` replace it with `i`

Answer (score 2):

You can not use "return" in the loop, it is used in functions. Also you might want to make pauses between plots:

```
par(ask=T)
for (i in 1:length(C)) {
  x <- C[i]
  counti <- table(data[,x])
  y <- barplot(counti, main=paste("Barplot for var", x))
  y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should unlearn is the `as.data.frame(cbind())` mistake. It forces all the columns to be of the same class, thereby defeating any benefits of the dataframe structure.

```
sapply(data, class)
       x        y        z 
"factor" "factor" "factor"
```

It's also going to be simpler to just use `A<- sapply(data, class)` as above and get a vector instead of that tortured pass through `cbind`. And as others have mentioned `return` works for regular functions but not inside a for-loop. If you were going to do it with a for-loop, you need to have a structure to gather the results of the barplot calls and a list is the natural one because you cannot be sure they will all be the same length. This might be an alternate route:

```
y <- LETTERS[as.integer(rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=1))]
z <- LETTERS[as.integer(rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=1))]
x <- round(rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=2.5),2)
data <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
CC <- grep("character|factor", sapply(data, class))
y <- list()
 for (i in seq_along(CC) ) {
   x <- CC[i]
   counti <- table(data[,x]) 
   y <- c(y, list(barplot( counti, main=paste("Barplot for var", x))))
   }
 y
#------------    
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
[4,]  4.3
[5,]  5.5
[6,]  6.7

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
[4,]  4.3
[5,]  5.5
[6,]  6.7
```

Comment: Many thanks for the most excellent guidance on form!  As someone who is about 8 months into my personal journey with R, I can certainly use the advice.

Comment: If you can remember who taught you to use `as.data.frame(cbind())` , I'd like to know so I can put a stop to it. It keeps appearing and seems to be increasing in prevalence.

Comment: @DWin I think it's kinda intuitive to paste things together and then turn it into a data frame if you think of `cbind` as an action and `data.frame` as an attribute.  I remember making the same mistake myself starting out with R.  It's intuition I think you're confronting, the only way to change it is to do exactly what you' just did...inform people.  : )

Answer (score 1):

I think something with lapply may be nicer:

```
C <- grep("character|factor", B)

FUN <- function(vec, num){
  if (dev.interactive()) dev.new()
  counti <- table(vec)
  y <- barplot(counti, main=paste("Barplot for var", num))
  return(y)
}

lapply(C, function(i) FUN(data[, i], i))
```